# $\mathbb{Z}G\otimes_{\mathbb{Z}N} \mathcal{N}= \mathcal{N}^G$ is a non-trivial idempotent ideal in $\mathbb{Z}G$

Tags: tensor-products, group-rings

Let $G$ be a group and $I_G$ be the augmentation ideal of the group ring $\mathbb{Z}G$, i.e. $I_G$ consists of formal linear combinations $\sum n_i g_i$ ($n_i\in\mathbb{Z}$, $g_i\in G$) such that $\sum n_i=0$. Now if $N$ is a normal subgroup of $G$, and $\mathcal{N} $ is augmentation ideal of $\mathbb{Z}N$ then why $\mathbb{Z}G\otimes_{\mathbb{Z}N} \mathcal{N}$= $\mathcal{N}^G$ is a non trivial idempotent ideal in $\mathbb{Z}G$.

What does  $(\mathbb{Z}G\otimes_{\mathbb{Z}N} \mathcal{N})\cdot(\mathbb{Z}G\otimes_{\mathbb{Z}N} \mathcal{N})$ look like? Is it $(\mathbb{Z}G)^2 \otimes (\mathcal{N})^2?$ Which would mean $(\mathbb{Z}G)^2 \otimes (\mathcal{N})^2= \mathbb{Z}G\otimes_{\mathbb{Z}N} \mathcal{N}$. Is it?

Comment: This doesn't seem to be true in case $G=\mathbb{Z}/2$ and $N=G$. Then if $\mathbb{Z}/2=\langle \eta\rangle$, an element of $\mathcal{N}\cong \mathbb{Z}G\otimes_{\mathbb{Z} G} \mathcal{N}$ is of the form $a-a\eta$, and products of such elements have both coefficients even.

Comment: @Bhaskar Vasishth please help me to solve this problem https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3025927/exponent-of-the-non-abelian-group-1jfg-for-finite-non-abelian-p-group-g thanks